# Centos6 - Log files copied from the server

Tags: linux, centos, logs

Is there a way to log any files copied from the server to a PC on the network? It would be a specific directory on the server (Centos 6).

I have tried searching for an answer to this but to no avail so thought I'd ask here.

Edit for clarity:
I just mean via the network.  So someone has navigated to \Server\MyFolder and copied the contents to their desktop using drag and drop

Comment: Copied how? To a networkshare, via `scp`, via `ftp`, the list goes on...?

Comment: Ah sorry! I just mean via the network.  So someone has navigated to \\Server\MyFolder and copied the contents to their desktop using drag and drop

Comment: Are you using `samba`?

Comment: Yes using Samba

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can! But each protocol has its method.

For **SAMBA** [doc here](https://www.samba.org/samba/docs/current/man-html/vfs_full_audit.8.html):

1. Add SAMBA audit module (already in your Samba, just enable it)
2. Edit `smb.conf`

   ```
   valid users = ...
   vfs objects = full_audit
   full_audit:failure = none
   full_audit:success = mkdir rename unlink rmdir open pwrite
   full_audit:prefix = %u|%I|%m|%S
   ```

For **NFS**:

You need to enable the debug mode:
`rpcdebug -m nfsd -s all`
And to stop it : `rpcdebug -m nfsd -c`

Comment: Hi! Thanks for this. Yes we are using SAMBA. Where would step 2 be entered? Within the share definition?

Comment: Yes, in the share definition ( `valid users` is a typical option from the share definition)

Comment: Note that, you don't have to add `valid users = ...` It is only for an example. you can add more options as well, as seen in the documentation.

Comment: Would this Question just need the "open" audit?